# Find the test statistic

Tags: probability, statistics

> A large orthodontist practice is investigating a new supplier for a dental bonding agent. One important
>   consideration is the breaking strength of the agent. It is well known from a very large amount of past
>   experience that the agent currently in use has a mean breaking strength of 6 Mpa. The new supplier is offering a new type of agent, one that would result in very large savings. One factor the orthodontist
>   wants to investigate is the breaking strength of the new agent. He uses the agent to affix a dental
>   appliance on each of 12 extracted teeth, and then measures the breaking strength. He finds that the
>   breaking strength has a sample mean of 4.8 Mpa with a sample standard deviation of 1.1 Mpa.
>   For such a small sample size (n = 12), it is a bit dubious to use the t procedures, as we cannot rely on
>   the Central Limit Theorem. But let's assume a normally distributed population here. Let's also assume that these observations can be thought of as a random sample from the population of interest. That's also a bit dubious, but let's go with it.
>
> Test the null hypothesis that the population mean breaking strength of the new agent is equal to 6.0
>   Mpa, against a two-sided alternative hypothesis.
>
> **What is the value of the appropriate test statistic?**

I am confused. I know that the population mean is 6 and the standard deviation is 1.1 and the sample size is 12 but what is the sample mean. 
So I used the formula of (sample mean - population mean/ standard deviation/square root of sample size)

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Using all caps is considered shouting on the internet, and it is extremely rude. Please don't ever do that again.

Answer (score 0):

Your "dubious" assumption is that $X_1,\ldots,X_{12} \sim \, \mathrm{i.i.d.} \, N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

The sample mean is $\bar X = \dfrac{X_1+\cdots+X_{12}} {12}$.

The sample variance is $S^2=\dfrac{(X_1-\bar X)^2 + \cdots + (X_{12}-\bar X)^2}{12 - 1}$.

The random variable $\dfrac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{12}}$ has a stardard normal distribution.

The statistic $\dfrac{\bar X - \mu}{S/\sqrt{12}}$ has a $t$ distribution with $11$ degrees of freedom.

The null hypothesis says $\mu=6$, so $\dfrac{\bar X - 6}{S/\sqrt{12}}$ would have a $t$ distribution with $11$ degrees of freedom.

The observed values of $\bar X$ and $S$ are $4.8$ and $1.1$.

Thus your test statistic is $\dfrac{4.8-6}{1.1/\sqrt{12}}$.